# Grid of rearrangeable images

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

There may already be a question related to this, but I do not know where to start searching for an answer.

I have a number of images (that the user drags onto a **HTML5** drop zone), and I would like to arrange them in a **grid format**. I have got the drop zone working pretty much the way I want it to.

The thing is that I need the user to be able to rearrange them, while still keeping them in a **grid form**. I would prefer it if you rearranged the images by dragging and dropping them.

Not all of the holes will be filled at all times. I need to know what order the images are in so that I can use that information to draw the images to a canvas in that order to provide a single image to export (this is for a simple tileset editor, like a **css sprite**). All of the images will be the same size.

I would **not** like to use **JQuery**.

Does anybody know of a good library that will help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you float them, will they not do what you want?

Comment: @mplugjan That is a good idea! How can I get you to be able to drag them around?

Comment: Hmm, I would use collision detection and swap places if dragged over a div lower in the hierarchy. I do not know other frameworks than jQuery for that

Comment: @mplugjan oh dear - I do not want to use jQuery if I can help it

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=html5+drag+drop+collision+detection

Comment: If you downvote, please leave a comment telling me how I can improve.

Comment: Likely due to lack of code - also library recommendations are off topic here

Comment: @mplungjan Right. Thanks! I will try and make my questions more relevant next time.